# How to copy and paste an autocad table using python

Tags: python, lisp, pywin32, autocad

I am trying to use pyautocad to copy a table from one autocad drawing and paste it in another. Its important that I retain the same table style and location as well. Afterwards the script populates the table.

I've tried using both the COPY and COPYBASE methods (below) but I am still being prompted to manually select the objects and insertion points. Does anyone know the proper way to do this?

```
import os, time
import pyautocad

def copy_table(source_file, dest_file):
    acad = pyautocad.Autocad(create_if_not_exists=True)
    os.startfile(source_file)
    time.sleep(5)
    source_doc = acad.ActiveDocument

    table = None
    for obj in acad.iter_objects('AcDbTable'):
        if obj.ObjectName == "AcDbTable":
            table = obj
            break

    if not table:
        print("Table not found in the source drawing.")
        return

    insertion_point = (1.15, 24.1162)

    try:
        acad.Application.SendCommand('ENTSEL\n')
        acad.Application.SendCommand(f'{table.Handle}\n')
        acad.Application.SendCommand(f'COPY\n')

        # I've also tried this but still got prompted to select the table
        source_doc.SendCommand(f"COPYBASE \n {table.Handle}\n {insertion_point[0]}\n {insertion_point[1]}\n")
        
        print("table selected")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    os.startfile(dest_file)
    time.sleep(5)
    dest_doc = acad.ActiveDocument

    # this part works
    dest_doc.SendCommand('_PASTECLIP\n' + str(insertion_point[0] + 0) + ',' + str(insertion_point[1] + 0) + '\n')
```

Comment: I was actually able to solve it by looking at the comments under this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78165903/autocad-using-pyautocad-comtypes-to-copy-objects-from-one-drawing-to-another

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer the question by utilizing the comments on this question: [Autocad using pyautocad / comtypes to copy objects from one drawing to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78165903/autocad-using-pyautocad-comtypes-to-copy-objects-from-one-drawing-to-another)

Working code below:

```
import os, time
import pyautocad

def copy_table(source_file, dest_file):
    acad = pyautocad.Autocad(create_if_not_exists=True)
    os.startfile(source_file)
    time.sleep(5)
    source_doc = acad.ActiveDocument

    table = None
    for obj in acad.iter_objects('AcDbTable'):
        if obj.ObjectName == "AcDbTable":
            table = obj
            break

    if not table:
        print("Table not found in the source drawing.")
        return


    handle_string = 'COPYBASE\n'
    handle_string += '0,0,0\n'  
    handle_string += '(handent "' + table.Handle + '")\n'
    handle_string += '\n'

    try:
        source_doc.SendCommand(handle_string)
        
        print("table selected")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    os.startfile(dest_file)
    time.sleep(5)
    dest_doc = acad.ActiveDocument

    # this part works
    dest_doc.SendCommand('_PASTECLIP\n' + '0,0,0\n')

    # Save changes and close documents
    source_doc.Close()
    dest_doc.Save()
    dest_doc.Close()

    print("Table copied successfully.")
```